# express-openid-connect how to specify grant type?

Tags: node.js, express, openid-connect

I am trying to connect to Openid Issuer and they allow only authorization code and refresh token for my client. I am using express-openid-connect and using the base configuarion to connect to the issuer. It comes back saying implicit grant type is not allowed for this client. How do I specify Authorization code in my request. Please help as I am new to this.

```
ISSUER_BASE_URL=//issuer URL
CLIENT_ID=//client ID
BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000 //nodejs project base URL
SECRET=<long string>


const express = require('express');
const { auth } = require('express-openid-connect');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();    

app.use(auth());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`hello ${req.oidc.user.name}`);
  //res.send("index")
});

app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
    res.send("logged in");
  });    

app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at http://localhost:3000'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in **app.use** to use authorization code:

```
app.use(
    auth({
    authorizationParams: {
      response_type: 'code',
      scope: 'openid profile email'
    },
  })
);
```

From https://auth0.github.io/express-openid-connect/interfaces/configparams.html#authorizationparams